# How to print 3d string in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

Please help me, now I am developing a screen saver by let the user input the string and I will bring this string to print out as a 3d string on the android mobile phone. Please suggest me in the android have function to do this or I have to use `openGL ES` to develop and how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there is only one way to do 3D graphics in Android: OpenGL ES.

As for drawing 3D text, there's no direct support in OpenGL itself; you have to turn the characters into polygons yourself, or use a 3rd-party routine to do that.

Here are a couple of articles on how to do the latter in OpenGL:

- http://www.videotutorialsrock.com/opengl_tutorial/draw_text/text.php
- http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/opengl/article.php/c2701

I don't if either of these use routines that are unavailable in OpenGL ES.

The example code is in C/C++, but hopefully it would give you a good start on doing the same in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The PowerVR Insider SDK contains Print3D which does 3D text rendering.

Comment: hm interesting... i'll take a look at it! txn